# Jquery Datepicker not working even though calling order is sequential

Tags: jquery, function, datepicker, undefined

I have the following syntax on a page:

```
<div class="filterDiv">
    <input class="txt" type="text" id="txtUsername" placeholder="Username" />
    <input class="txt" type="text" id="txtFault" placeholder="Fault ID" /><br />

    <input type="text" id="txtDateFrom" class="picker" placeholder="From" />
    <input type="text" id="txtDateTo" class="picker" placeholder="To" /><br />

    <input type="button" value="Filter" onclick="Filter();" />
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Styles/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#txtDateFrom').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        $('#txtDateTo').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
    });
.......
```

I am still getting a 'Undefined is not a function' error at runtime for the datepicker.

JQuery UI is v1.10.4 if that matters.

Has anyone encountered this before and has solved it?

Comment: PS: The IDs have been fixed to match, this was only an earlier version  which i didn't realise still had those IDs :)

Comment: It is because of id mismatch. please check the link http://jsfiddle.net/Vw4Am/

Comment: In my second comment I added that that has already been fixed. It was just a typo while posting this question :)

Comment: Solved. This was related to the project being an MVC4 project. For those with the same issue, I went to _layout.cshtml in the Shared views folder, and moved @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") from the bottom of the page to the layout page's header.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery folder path mentioned is wrong it seems because the same worked for me.

Check this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="filterDiv">
    <input class="txt" type="text" id="txtUsername" placeholder="Username" />
    <input class="txt" type="text" id="txtFault" placeholder="Fault ID" /><br />

    <input type="text" id="txtDateFrom" class="picker" placeholder="From" />
    <input type="text" id="txtDateTo" class="picker" placeholder="To" /><br />

    <input type="button" value="Filter" onclick="Filter();" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {   
    $('#txtDateFrom').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
    $('#txtDateTo').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: check this edited code now. :) Also add the jquery-ui.css if the same works for u to.

Comment: Adding `scripts` to the `head` tag will not fix the error.  It is highly recommended to add `scripts` at the end of the `body` tag.   Therefore your answer will not work.  As I already suspected the problem is in [*another part of the code*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154287/jquery-datepicker-not-working-even-though-calling-order-is-sequential#comment35406314_23154287).